# Extract Parameter Pack

Tags: c++

I want to write a function taking `N` arguments of type `T`. The use case is to initialize an array in a class with an initializer list.

```
Vector<uint8_t, 3> vector {5, 4, 3} 
Vector<uint16_t, 2> vector2 {90, 7}
```

The reason, I don't use `std::initalizer` list is that for the platform I develop, no standard library is available. Therefore I tried some approaches with a self-made `integer_list` (similar to the one from `std`).

```
template <uint8_t ... Ints >
class IndexSequence {};
```

This works perfectly fine (`Array` is also similiar to `std::array`):

```
template <typename T, uint8_t I>
using ParamPack = T;

template <typename T, uint8_t N, typename I = makeIndexSequence<N>>
class Test;

template <typename T, uint8_t N, uint8_t... I>
class Test<T, N, IndexSequence<I...>> {

public:
 Test(ParamPack<T, I>... v)
 : data {v...} {}
private:
 Array<T,N> data;
};
```

But I don't like this "trick" to extract the integer param pack from integerSequece so much, because the integer param pack is now part of the class template. And I actually would prefer it just in a template of the constructor or even without any templates.

For example something like this:

```
Test(ParamPack<T, makeIndexSequence<N>.getParamPack()>... v)
```

Or something similar. This would be much cleaner in my opinion.
Is there any way to extract the Param Pack from `integerSequence` without having the param pack in the class template?

I tried to use the same trick just with a template of a function. Unfortunately, it doesn't work, because functions cannot be partially specialised.

Maybe you even have a completely different approach to have something like `std::initializer_list` or Param packs of a specific type (I'm aware of the possibility to just use variadic templates and cast it into T, but I would like to avoid this if there is a better solution).

Comment: Have you heard of "freestanding" implementations of C++/the standard library, that contain only zero-cost portions of the std library?  Second, what about the name being part of the class is the problem; debugging?  Symbol length?  Random squick?

Comment: I guess this is a port of the std library? My platform is avr, an 8-bit microcontroller. I think there exist some tries to port the std, but they aren't very good. The reason I don't want to have it like this is that the class I want to use it, is actually also a partial specialisation. And then I have also this template paramter in the base class etc. ... It's possible, but it makes the code look more complex than it should

Comment: If array is similar to `std::array` so you could use aggregate initialization. Does you class establish any invariant?

Comment: Aggregate initalization is used to create the array. It's basically just a c-array in a wrapper. But in the class I use it, it's private so I can't use aggreagte initalization I suppose. I implemented a constructor like this: Test(Array<T, N>&& data); ... so I can use it like this ... Test<uint8_t, 3> test {{1,2,3}}; ... but I don't like the double braces ... just syntactic sugar :)

Comment: @Leon0402 What about making it public with a non trivial name like _iner_array. Access control can easily be bypassed whatsoever. And you will not be the first to do that: the inner c-array of all `std::array` is a public member.

Comment: In my Array class it is public ... that's perfectly fine. But in any class where I use my std::array I want to have it private. Usually people use std::initalizer_list in this case ... but it's somehow part of the compiler. So I need another solution. I know that there is probably not a solution which is as beautiful as the std::initalizer_list, but I suppose the current solution can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to avoid variadic templates? They are the right way to solve these kind of problems.

There is no easy way of generating a dynamic number of parameters from a static value `N`. All solutions involve specialization for some sort of variadic input (`std::index_sequence` does exactly the same, it generates variadic template parameters).

I think the most elegant way is to use variadic templates and protect the input using `static_assert`.

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class Test {
 public:
  template <typename... Ts>
  Test(Ts&&... v) : data{std::forward<Ts>(v)...} {
    static_assert(sizeof...(Ts) == N, "invalid number of arguments");
    static_assert((std::is_same_v<T, Ts> && ...), "wrong type");
  }

 private:
  std::array<T, N> data;
};
```

Note that I am using `std::array` in this example. It fails to compile when you pass an invalid type or invalid number of arguments.

```
Test<int, 2> a{1, 2}; // compiles
Test<int, 2> b{1}; // invalid number of arguments
Test<int, 2> c{1, 2, 3}; // invalid number of arguments
Test<int, 2> d{1, 2.f}; // wrong type
```

Comment: I'm sorry I probably have not made clear enough my point. I used this approach before (just without std as it's not available) ... but usually 1 or 2 are interpreted as ints ... when I use Test<uint8_t, 2> a {1,2} ... there is a cast from int to uint8_t ... but actually the numbers could be interpreted directly as uint8_t. I just wondered if there is any solution without the cast, but nicer than my.

Comment: Thats's not correct. The input `{1, 2}` will be checked at compile-time, there is no cast. Try to pass `12345679` or an `int`-lvalue, it won't compile and you have to perform an explicit cast. The same applies for your custom constructor accepting `uint8_t`s only. When you pass a type that requires narrowing, you have to perform explicit casts (so, technically, both solutions are the same).

Comment: I don't want implicit casts neither explicit cast. I just wanted the values 1 or 2 be directly of type T. Just imagine the constructor Test(T param1, T param2) ... if I then write Test<uint8_t, 2> test {1,2} ... the 1 and the 2 will be interpreted as uint8_t wiouth any cast (as far as I know). For your solution or any solution with static_cast, the 1 or 2 will be first an int (int16_t on my platform I suppose) and will then be casted (either implicitly or with a static_cast explicitly) in a uint8_t. So I need this constructor with params of Type T , but with N params.

Comment: I know that this isn't really a real problem as static_cast actually would be totaly fine. I'm still curious if there is any solution to have a std::initalizer_list or variadic templates of a specific type ... or my solution as described in the question. Although it isn't really relevant this question showed me a lot new things (for example about index Sequence, partial specialisation, some temlate tricks etc.). So I'm interested in other solutions one may know.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that there is no scenario in which implicit narrowing is performed (any other input is permitted). Of course, you have to pass the correct type (and `6` is no `uint8_t`). I understand that my solution doesn't solve your problem.